# visual studio code - node js error with typescript debug configuration

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual studio code editor 0.5 version. My debug configuration file:

```
{
     "name": "Launch app",
     "type": "node",
     "program": "src/server/app.ts",
     "stopOnEntry": false,
     "sourceMaps": true,
     "outDir": "src/server/"
}
```

I have compiled all files, but when I run in debug, I get this error:
[image: node js error]

But if I set sourceMaps to false and program back to src/server/app.js it works and I get break point hit at my app.js. Is this is visual studio code bug?

Comment: Consider writing your own answer and accepting that instead of writing the solution in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a mistake. I'm using gulp-typescript and gulp-sourcemaps plugins and gulp-sourcemaps generate different source maps compared to tsc compiler, this is why this error occured. I was able to fix it only by doing some hacks for gulp-sourcemaps plugin. But I still not sure if this is gulp-sourcemaps bug or visual studio code bug so I will try to register bug for vs code.